# Apply a value to max values in a groupby

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a DF like this:

```
  ID     Time
  1      20:29
  1      20:45
  1      23:16
  2      11:00
  2      13:00
  3      01:00
```

I want to create a new column that puts a 1 next to the largest time value within each ID grouping like so:

```
  ID     Time     Value
  1      20:29      0
  1      20:45      0
  1      23:16      1  
  2      11:00      0
  2      13:00      1
  3      01:00      1
```

I know the answer involves a groupby mechanism and have been fiddling around with something like:

```
df.groupby('ID')['Time'].max() = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to write an anonymous function that operates on each of your groups and feed this to your groupby using `apply`:

```
df['Value']=df.groupby('ID',as_index=False).apply(lambda x : x.Time == max(x.Time)).values
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your 'Time' column is already a `datetime64` then you want to `groupby` on 'ID' column and then call `transform` to apply a lambda to create a series with an index aligned with your original df:

```
In [92]:
df['Value'] = df.groupby('ID')['Time'].transform(lambda x: (x == x.max())).dt.nanosecond
df

Out[92]:
   ID                Time  Value
0   1 2015-11-20 20:29:00      0
1   1 2015-11-20 20:45:00      0
2   1 2015-11-20 23:16:00      1
3   2 2015-11-20 11:00:00      0
4   2 2015-11-20 13:00:00      1
5   3 2015-11-20 01:00:00      1
```

The `dt.nanosecond` call is because the dtype returned is a datetime for some reason rather than a boolean:

```
In [93]:
df.groupby('ID')['Time'].transform(lambda x: (x == x.max()))

Out[93]:
0   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000000
1   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000000
2   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000001
3   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000000
4   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000001
5   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000001
Name: Time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: is dt a new feature of pandas -- I get an error when that functionality is called?

Comment: introduced in [`0.15.0`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0150-dt)